# Shaka player one track auto play loop - streaming forever instead of once

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, webm, shaka

I am streaming and looping one video track, I'd like it to be downloaded fully only once, while the first loop is playing, and than to play the rest of the loops from storage.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Have you read the offline storage tutorial at https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-offline.html ? You can download the video segments and then you can play from stored segments.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered on GitHub in [shaka-player#1459](https://github.com/google/shaka-player/issues/1459), but I'll repeat it here for anyone who comes across this question.

Assuming the video is small, you can set the `bufferingGoal` and `bufferBehind` configuration values to the length of the video (or larger) and it will buffer the whole video.  Then you can just set the video to loop and the browser will play it without downloading anything more.  But since the whole video is stored in memory, this can only be done for short videos.

```
player.configure({streaming: {bufferBehind: 60, bufferingGoal: 60}});
```